# how to move to your desired page after DEVISE AUTHENTICATION in Rails

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby-on-rails-3, ruby-on-rails-3.1, devise, ruby-on-rails-3.2

I am using Devise in my rails app to authenticate.
After signing in from sign in page it doesn't go to any other page. How do I configure Devise to move to my desired page after authenticating from sign-in page ?

Right now it is coming back to sign in page.

My sign in page is as follow:

```
<h2>Sign in ! Hussain</h2>

<h2><%= resource%></h2>

<h2><%= resource_name%></h2>


<%= form_for(resource, :as => resource_name, :url => session_path(resource_name)) do |f| %>
  <div><%= f.label :email %><br />
  <%= f.email_field :email, :autofocus => true %></div>

  <div><%= f.label :password %><br />
  <%= f.password_field :password %></div>

  <% if devise_mapping.rememberable? -%>
    <div><%= f.check_box :remember_me %> <%= f.label :remember_me %></div>
  <% end -%>

  <div><%= f.submit "Sign in" %></div>
<% end %>

<%= render "devise/shared/links" %>
```

Comment: I suspect your form is producing errors.  They aren't being displayed due to not having error output in your view.

Comment: then it should show some errors , but what it simply goes back to same page , with an error in the console unauthenticated , where i am entering correct credentials

Comment: I'm referring to devise errors... have you not tried putting <%= devise_error_messages!%> in your form to see what it might be saying?

Answer (score 1):

You can do this by overriding the default methods of devise i.e. `after_sign_in_path_for` in `application_controller`. Check out [Devise documentation](https://github.com/plataformatec/devise/wiki/_pages). For your problem you can follow [this link](https://github.com/plataformatec/devise/wiki/How-To%3a-Redirect-to-a-specific-page-after-a-successful-sign-in-or-sign-out).

Hope that helps!!!